# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empController'

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am integrating spring MVC + hibernate using java based configuration and trying to use transaction management but is throwing some exception and I am  unable to figure out to root cause and how to fix this

I have created employee controller, repository, repositoryImpl, service, serviceImpl, configuration class and i have added all needed dependencies in pom.xml

---

Exception

---

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService': Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Amiti\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\api\WEB-INF\classes\com\amiti\hibernate\EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Amiti\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\api\WEB-INF\classes\com\amiti\hibernate\EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Amiti\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\api\WEB-INF\classes\com\amiti\hibernate\EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:118)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 38 more

May 07, 2019 5:06:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/api] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:118)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

### POM.XML

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

---

### Service Impl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO dao;

    public long save(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dao.save(employee);
    }

    public Employee get(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dao.get(id);
    }

}
```

---

### RepositoryImpl

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public long save(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
        return employee.getId();
    }

    public Employee get(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Employee.class, id);
    }

}
```

---

### Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.amiti.hibernate", "com.amiti.api", "com.amiti.validation", "com.amiti.interceptor",
        "com.amiti.exception" })
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


      @Autowired private Environment env;

      @Override public void
      configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
      System.out.println("configured"); configurer.enable(); }


    /*
     * @Override public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     * registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor()); registry.addInterceptor(new
     * LogInterceptor()); }
     */


      @Bean 
      public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
      System.out.println("view"); InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new
      InternalResourceViewResolver(); viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp"); return viewResolver; }

      @Bean 
      public MessageSource messageSource() { System.out.println("source");
      ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      source.setBasename("messages"); return source; }

      @Bean 
      public DataSource dataSource() { System.out.println("datasource");
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); // MySQL database we are using
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee");// change url
      dataSource.setUsername("root");// change userid
      dataSource.setPassword("admin");// change pwd 
      return dataSource; 
      }

      Properties hibernateProperties() { return new Properties() { {
      setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
      setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true"); } }; }

      @Bean public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource()); sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
      new String[] { "org.amiti.hibernate" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory; }

      @Bean 
      public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
      HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new
      HibernateTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject()); return
      transactionManager; }

      @Bean public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() { System.out.println("template");
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
      jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource()); return jdbcTemplate; }

}
```

I want to integrate hibernate with spring mvc with transaction management

Comment: add detailed code to find out where and which dependencies are failing

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars from different versions of Spring. You are at least mixing 4.2 and 5.1 jars. Which is also the root cause judging from the stacktrace `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getQualifiedMethodName` those generally stem from mixing incompatible versions. You have a property for the spring version use it everywhere you want a spring framework dependency.

Comment: so what which jar version i have to change

Comment: Use only one version of spring jars. Use 4.2 or use 5.1.6

Comment: Search for org.springframework group id in pom.xml and change the version according to your use

Comment: Thank you, I changed my jar version and this resolved my problem